# html5 - How to check for shapes drawn on canvas?

Tags: html, drawing, html5-canvas

I have made a webpage on which there's a canvas on which we can draw freehandly. Now I wanted to know that is there's a way to find that the user has now drawn a "square", "circle" or "rectangle"? I mean that if I draw a square on the canvas, how can I write the code to check that I have drawn a square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not many details to work with from you.

Also, “freehand” means very imprecise shapes.

So here’s a generic answer to determine your shape:

Determine the bounding box of a freehand shape (minX,maxX,minY,maxY).

Test#1:  if (maxX-minX) is largely different from (maxY-minY), then you have a rectangle.

Test#2: Walk one of corners towards the center.  If you quickly cross part of the drawing, you have a square.

By process of elimination, if Test#1 and Test#2 fail, then you have a circle.